# Golang: Global vars scope and routines

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand a problem I have using a global var and a routine.
I created a simplifed test case to demonstrate:

```
var _i int = 5

func main() {
    fmt.Println("a _i", _i)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("b _i", _i)
        update()
    }()
    ...
}
    
func update() {
    fmt.Println("c _i", _i)
}
```

It correctly returns

```
a _i 5
b _i 5
c _i 5
```

But if I initialise my var inside main:

```
var _i int

func main() {
    _i := 5
    fmt.Println("a _i", _i)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("b _i", _i)
        update()
    }()
    ...
}
    
func update() {
    fmt.Println("c _i", _i)
}
```

It returns

```
a _i 5
b _i 5
c _i 0
```

Anybody can explain what I'm missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last version you initialized _i with `_i := 5` the `:=` creates a new _i that shadows the global one. This is why update() prints 0, the global _i was never set to anything. You can change your initialization to `_i = 5` to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The second program declares local variable `_i` in `main()` using a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

The print in the anonymous function uses the local variable in `main()`.  The local variable has value `5`. The print in the `update()` function uses the package-level variable. The package-level variable has value `0`.

Fix by [assigning](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignments) to `_i` in `main()`:

```
func main() {
    _i = 5 // <-- colon removed from this line.
    fmt.Println("a _i", _i)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("b _i", _i)
        update()
    }()
    ...
}
```